# Wifi not working anymore (possibly because of installation of CUDA drivers and/or nvidia-smi)

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, nvidia, cuda

I installed nvidia CUDA drivers and `nvidia-smi` on a Debian system where I had no wifi problems until now.
I tried many `sudo apt install` commands and downloaded some `*.deb` files until I *finally* got the CUDA drivers and executable working.

However, after rebooting the computer, wifi won't work anymore. I have to assume that this is a consequence of my installation attempts.

The only hint I can currently offer is that I find the following entry in the kernel log:

```
sudo dmesg | grep wifi
[    9.594581] iwlwifi 0000:6f:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   10.238717] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:6f:00.0 failed with error -110
```

I have no idea where or how I should proceed now.